# Does there exist a $c: P(X<c)=2P(X>c)$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

The proportion of impurities in a certain compound is a random variable with
density $f(x) = k x (1-x)$, where x belongs to $[0,2]$.

1. Calculate $k$.
2. Find the accumulated function.
3. Find $c$, a constant, such that $P(X < c)= 2 P(X>c)$.
4. Calculate the density of $Y=2/X$.

I found $k=3$ and accumulated function is $x^2-x$

But task 3 seems not to be possible for me. I've tried but can't reach any solution.

Or maybe the function I've found is wrong?
Anybody knows?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hey @Bey thank you and you are right, where i'm wrong  ? Please tell me so i can fix, and sorry for that, english is not my first language at all .

Comment: @TheNewStudent I clarified your title so it is clearer what you are actually asking -- other than that the question seems fine to me.

Comment: @Bey  Very very  very thank you.

Comment: $x$ belongs to $[0,2]$, but $f(2)$ is negative. (Or at least one of $f(0.5)$ and $f(1.5)$ is negative)

Comment: Consider editing the title to make it informative. ”Valor of letter c is possible?” says nothing about the subject of the problem.

Comment: I had edited the title but it doesn't seem my edits were accepted.

Comment: Check the new wording of the question carefully to see if it is correct after the edit. The part about $x$ in $[0,2]$ in particular looks wrong (and looked even worse before the edit). My guess is the question was supposed to say $x$ is in the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: yeah, the domain doesn't make sense here

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=P(X<c)$. Then the condition: $\exists c:P(X<c) = 2P(X>c)$ is the same as saying:

$$\exists p \in [0,1]: p = 2(1-p) = 2 - 2p \implies 3p=2 \implies p=\frac{2}{3}$$

So you're looking for the 66th percentile of your variable.

Comment: Very thank you so the acumulated function that  i've found is right  ? it is realy x^2 - x ? and k = 3 ? i'm not sure about these results. But it seen's to make sense to me

Comment: it'seens i have to study more my god, i realy have to study hard :(

Comment: @TheNewStudent no, k=6, assuming $x\in[0,1]$ Here's a resource I recommend (WolframAlpha) so you can check your work: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%281-x%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: @TheNewStudent as others have pointed out, the function $x(1-x)$ becomes negative after $x=1$ so you can't have a density defined over $[0,2]$ Are you sure the problem isn't  $x \in [0,1]$?